# I don't understand how to list JSON with params like ?currentPage=0&pageSize=18

Tags: php, json

Can someone please show me some examples or show me how, I already got the parms working but I don't know how I would do the api what im trying to do is make it get the data from my database with the currentpage and pagesize/limit I have got limit to work but I cant figure out how I would do current page

This is what I've got so far

```
<?php
require ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/core/config.php");
require ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/core/session.php");

if ($logged == false) {
    header('Location: /');
    exit;
}

    $limit = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['pageSize']);

if(intval($limit)) {
    $sqlSearch = "SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT $limit";
    $result = $conn->query($sqlSearch);

    while ($userrows = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $username = $userrows['username'];

        $apiresp = array('success' => "true", 'username' => $username);
        echo json_encode($apiresp);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question

Comment: The good news about this snippet being public is that nearly none of it should make its way into production code.  Rest easy.  You will need to build up the fully populated array before encoding and echoing.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use offset

```
SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT $limit,". ($page -1)*$limit;
```

Comment: @Yunnosch We're not in the habit of doing that, unless a DMCA takedown is filed against the question.